# I want to display the bidirectional relationship between 2 nodes only once

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a weighted graph, some of the nodes have bidirectional relationships with the same weight. I want to display those nodes in tabular form only once.

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n1) 
RETURN  n1.prefered_name ,r1.weight,r2.weight, n2.prefered_name;
```

[image: Result of this query, but I want to show me only one row]

This code gives me exactly what I need but in doubles.

If I have 2 relationships between 2 nodes (pointing in a different direction) having the same weight I would like to show me only once the specific row.
Is this achievable? or because it is bidirectional relationships it has to show me twice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the pattern matches both ways you just need to add a `WHERE` clause to limit the output to only return the match in one direction.

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n1)
WHERE id(n1) > id(n2)
RETURN  n1.prefered_name ,r1.weight,r2.weight, n2.prefered_name;
```

Comment: thank you very much, this works even faster than the previous answer.

Answer (score 2):

This query is similar to @DaveBennett's, but only filters out a row if both relationships have the same weight:

```
MATCH (n1)-[r1:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n2)-[r2:HAS_DESCENDANT]->(n1)
WHERE r1.weight <> r2.weight OR ID(n1) > ID(n2)
RETURN n1.prefered_name, r1.weight, r2.weight, n2.prefered_name;
```

*By the way, it is unintuitive for `n1` and `n2` to be "descendants" of each other. If this is intentional, you may want to change the name of the relationship type to something less confusing.*